# received items from bluetooth not as printed ones

Tags: c++, bluetooth, arduino

i am developing a project that i send some numbers via bluetooth to the arduino mega board, so when i print the sent items directly they show correct. but when i store these numbers in an array and try to print them they show as different numbers. The numbers are sent as integers from my smartphone. here is my code:

```
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>// import the serial library

  SoftwareSerial Genotronex(51, 11); // RX, TX
  int BluetoothData; // the data given from Computer
  boolean oneTime = true;  //ensures data is received only once
  int myInts[1000];
  int counter = 0; // count the number of sent items

void setup() {

 Genotronex.begin(9600);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Bluetooth On");
 pinMode(ledpin,OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {

 if (Genotronex.available() && oneTime == true){
    BluetoothData=Genotronex.read();
    Serial.println(BluetoothData);                //  <== This shows the right numbers
    myInts[counter] = BluetoothData;             //add the integers in an array
    counter++;

if (BluetoothData==231){  // to know that the array is fully sent once
  oneTime = false;
  Serial.println("Done");
  counter--;                       //i dont want to print the last element 
  for(int a=0; a < counter; a=a+2){
    Serial.print("Bearing: ");
    Serial.print((myInts[a]));          //  <== This shows wrong numbers
    Serial.print("     ");
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println((myInts[a]+2));
  }

}
 }

delay(100);// prepare for next data ...


}
```

can someone please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made a silly mistake

```
 Serial.println((myInts[a]+2));
```

should be

```
Serial.println((myInts[a+1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
Serial.print((myInts[a]));
```

should be

```
 Serial.println((myInts[a]));
```

to be able to print ints as ASCII.

Comment: no sorry, this didn't solve the problem. i did a silly mistake in the second print line.